# How to create return order for guest user?

Tags: angular, sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

currenlty spartacus doesn't support return order for guest user, it will only supports registered customers, we need to authenticate guest user, when he is returning an order but unable to do so, is there any guards we need to customize, can anuyone help me here ?

Comment: ReturnOrderComponent is used for returns and is controlled with AuthGuard. I do not recommend that you edit AuthGuard to accept users who are not logged in. I think it would be better if you prepare a custom component that includes return processes for guest users.